# Read values from consul while bootstrap spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I have question is there any way to retrieve certain values and inject them to bootstrap.yml while application is coming up.

I have configuration file like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myApp

  cloud:
    consul:
      enabled: true
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      config:
        enabled: true

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1111:XXXX
    username: ${nameOfVariable1}
    password: ${nameOfVariable1}
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

For example, I need to configure embedded tomcat port, or DB credentials, I don't want to put it hardcoded in .yml properties file, instead I want to put some variable name in .yml so Spring will go and bring value from Consul. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Spring Cloud Consul Config` project that helps to load configuration into the Spring Environment during the special "bootstrap" phase.

3 steps:

1. add pom dependency: `spring-cloud-starter-consul-config`
2. enable consul config: `spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=true`
3. add some config in consul kv in specific folder, such as key: `config/testConsulApp/server.port`, value:8081

and then start the sample web app, it will listen 8081.

more detail at [spring cloud consul doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/single/spring-cloud-consul.html#spring-cloud-consul-config).

and [demo code here](https://github.com/tianzhipeng-git/spring-cloud-consul/tree/config-demo/spring-cloud-consul-sample/src/main)